# Example of Galois group of order $96$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am trying to think of an example of an extension $K\supset \mathbb Q$ so that Gal$(K/\mathbb Q)$ has order $96$.

I realize that it must be that $[K:\mathbb Q]=96$, but I am blanking. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $n\geq 3$ is an integer and $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $\phi(n)$. In particular, if $n=p$ is prime, then the degree is $p-1$.

Now you just have to observe that $97$ is prime.

Comment: Also, $193 = 96\times 2 + 1$  is also a prime, so $\mathbb{Q}(\cos{\frac{2\pi}{193}})$ is a real Galois extension of degree $96$.

Answer (score 0):

An easy example has already been given by Carmichael561. Here are two constructions which are  a bit more complicated.

Let $\zeta\ne1$ be a (complex) root of the polynomial equation $X^7-1=0$ and $\alpha$ be a root of $X^{32}+1=0$. Then the field generated by the two numbers $\alpha, \zeta+\bar\zeta$ over the rationals will be of degree 96. Individually they generate fields of degree 32 and 3. It is not difficult to show their composite is of degree 96.

There is another construction: Take 48 different prime numbers, the field generated by the square roots of all of them put together is of degree 96.

EDIT: the second example is wrong and as the commentator has said is of degree $2^48$.

Comment: The field over $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by 48 different prime numbers should have degree $2^{48}$.

Comment: @pisco125: Thanks for pointing out my stupid mistake. Anyway I retained  the mistake with warning as an edit.